# Creating a timestamp in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm struggling a little creating a timestamp in a format that I want using a scripted pipeline in Jenkins. Here's my code from the pipeline:

```
def cal = Calendar.instance
def dateFormat = 'YYYYMMDD-hhmmss'
def timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone('CST')
def timeStamp = cal.time​.format(dateFormat,timeZone)​
println "Timestamp is: ${timeStamp}"
env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP = timeStamp
```

When I run via Jenkins, I get the following:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified field java.util.GregorianCalendar time​
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:387)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:371)
```

I've seen mention of similar issues with different fields online, but the workaround of adding it to `scriptapproval.xml` (and restarting Jenkins) doesn't seem to be working.

Anyone have a method of generating a timestamp in a format similar to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you checked the In-process Script Approval page under Manage Jenkins? At the end it does the same as writing the scriptapproval.xml, but gives you some info about exactly what should be approved.

Comment: @babsaai Yes. I've checked that out. There's nothing in there to approve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out a way around it. I was accessing the field `time` directly. If I change the call from `cal.time` to `cal.getTime()` Jenkins behaves a lot better. I consolidated it into a one-liner, but the functionality's the same:

```
def timeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().format('YYYYMMdd-hhmmss',TimeZone.getTimeZone('CST'))
```

Thanks to those that had a look.

Comment: any dependencies required?

Answer (score 0):

Or use `Date()` formatted with `SimpleDateFormat()`:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
def date = new Date()
def timestamp = dateFormat.format(date)
```